# Periodic Table Software

Tags: windows-7, software-rec

Can you recommend a free software that I can access the Periodic Table with, that has the following features and runs Windows 7 32-bit;

- Accessible offline
- Full Periodic Table data
- Ability to look up by; atomic weight, number, full name of element, perhaps some detail about it, etc - what group the element belongs in.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: Any more detail, i.e., what do you need that a PNG wouldn't tell you http://www.google.com/images?q=periodic+table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Periodic Table Explorer](http://www.freshney.org/education/pte/index.htm) looks pretty good.  I have the mobile version on my iPhone.

[image: Periodic Table Explorer]

Comment: @studiohack:  It's a British geek offering free educational software to everyone.  It's all quite altruistic.  http://www.freshney.org/about.htm

Comment: all i can say is **wow**.  a must have for anyone studying science/chemistry/anything requiring the periodic table. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I understand that your requirements are offline, but Ptable.com has far more features than any of these applications, and it supports caching to be used offline. Visit the site once with your browser, click Properties, and then you can Work Offline or revisit with no Internet connection and it will continue to function. You won't have access to the Wikipedia-referenced writeups, but the Properties and Orbitals tab will fully function, complete with all their visualization options.

Answer (score 1):

### [Periodic Table (for Windows)](http://www.mchmultimedia.com/store/files/egoods/Periodic%20Table.exe)

[image]

- [Details](http://techblissonline.com/the-periodic-table/)
- [Application homepage](http://www.mchmultimedia.com/store/chemistry-freeware.html)

Comment: details? need more than the download .exe file.

Comment: Please see my edit.